# What does this operator() syntax do?

Tags: c++, templates

In this piece of code taken from http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403774:

```
template <class L, class R>
class MinResult {
    L& lhs_;
    R& rhs_;
public:
    operator L&() { return lhs_ < rhs_ ? lhs_ : rhs_; }   // <----
    operator R&() { return lhs_ < rhs_ ? lhs_ : rhs_; }   // <----
    MinResult(L& lhs, R& rhs) : lhs_(lhs), rhs_(rhs) {}
};
```

**What is the code above trying to do at lines pointed by arrows?**

I am a beginner in C++ and I understand that we can override / define `operator()` by defining it.

But then shouldn't it be defined like this

```
L& operator() { return lhs_ < rhs_ ? lhs_ : rhs_; }
```

I am sure this is some differenct syntax since `operator()` is supposed to be one word. Also, you cannot define two of them with different return types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No this is type cast operator.

You can define

```
operator type() const
```

As operator that allows to cast to the `type`. For example

```
class date {
public:
   operator time_t() const; // convert to time_t
};
```

The `operator()` has a different purpose, it allows to use the class as "function" and this is not the case here

Comment: Any particular reason we would typecast to a reference?

Comment: `type operator() const` should be written as `operator type() const`

Comment: Or `type operator()() const` if it is a function call operator taking no parameters.

Comment: @Lazer: In general, you'd return a reference if you want to use it for assignment. For example a container's `operator[]` returns a reference to an object in the container, so you can do `container[i] = x;`. In this case, it's a very bad idea - in some cases, these operators will return a reference to a temporary value, which is something you must never do. (That's in addition to the ambiguity problem that the article describes).